# Checkbox in react-native 0.47V

Tags: checkbox, react-native, android-checkbox

I am trying to put checkbox in react-native app. But when i searched for it i did not found checkbox in react-native version 0.47 documentation. Is there any external library to use ?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.47/checkbox.html Only support on android

Answer (score 0):

`react-native 0.47` have checkbox component.

Please see doc https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.47/checkbox.html

This component support on android only, for iOS You have to use switch.

Comment: Thank you Kishan but now i am not getting the example of checkbox so that i could get idea how to implement all props.

Comment: This could help you https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9f33fe258312987f490cc0f3a71c0c4f93494e7f/RNTester/js/CheckBoxExample.js

Comment: Checkbox is not working for react-native 0.47. I have used import {CheckBox} from 'react-native' and then in render method within <View> tags i wrote <CheckBox/>. But it didn't worked. Although there was no red screen or error but showing blank screen. So i have to implement external library for Checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using react-native-checkbox

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-checkbox

Comment: Thank you, but i want to use checkbox provided by react-native

Comment: you're welcome, i just answer following your question.

Comment: yes actually i was searching for react-native checkbox for v0.47 but i was not getting it so when i saw Kishan's post so i answered you. Don't mind it.